# Why does this code won't run my bldc motor?

Tags: arduino

I need to run my BLDC motor. I stumble upon this code where it enables me to move my BLDC motor using by pressing the numbers on the keypad.This code enables me to press the keypad number and setting the motor to the desired rpm. But my motor does not seem to run at all. Please tell me the problem and maybe a suggestion to why my BLDC motor won't run.

Here is the code:

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 5; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //four columns
//define the cymbols on the buttons of the keypads
char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2, 3, 4, 5}; 
byte colPins[COLS] = {6, 7, 8, 9}; 
//initialize an instance of class NewKeypad
Keypad customKeypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); 

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5);



char key_value='0';
char key_value1='0';

int RPM_Pin = 10;    // LED connected to digital pin 9
char key_start_stop='#';
char RPM_Timer='A';
String timer="00";
String timer1="00";
String timer2="00";
int  toggle=1;
int  toggle1=0;
int T=10;
long v_time=0;
String RPM="0000";
String RPM1="0000";
String RPM2="0000";
int  toggle_RPM=0;
int settings=0;
boolean settings_bit=false;
void setup()
{
  pinMode(RPM_Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RPM_Pin, LOW);
  analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 0);


  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col1 
  lcd.print("00; T1");


  lcd.setCursor(12, 2);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col1 
  lcd.print("0000");


  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop()
{
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();

  if (customKey)
  {
    Serial.println(customKey);


    if (customKey=='*' || customKey=='#' || customKey=='A' || customKey=='B' || customKey=='C')
    {

        if (customKey=='*')
        {
           key_start_stop = customKey;
           T=timer.toInt();

           key_value=RPM[2]; 
           key_value1=RPM[3]; 
           toggle_RPM=0;

           if (settings==1)
           {
              settings_bit=true;
           }
           else
           {
              settings_bit=false;
           }

        }
        else if (customKey=='#')
        {
           key_start_stop = customKey;


           toggle1=1;
           settings=0;
           T=0;
        }

        else if (customKey=='A')
        {
           RPM_Timer=customKey;
           lcd.setCursor(12, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col12 
           lcd.print("; T"); 
        }

        else if (customKey=='B')
        {
           RPM_Timer=customKey;
           lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
           lcd.print("; R"); 
        }

        else if (customKey=='C')
        {
           RPM_Timer='A'; 
           settings++;
           if (settings>=3)
           {
              settings=0;
           }

           if (settings==1)
           {
              lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
              lcd.print(timer1);
              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
              lcd.print("; T2"); 


              lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
              lcd.print(RPM1[3]);
              lcd.print(RPM1[2]);
              lcd.print(RPM1[1]);
              lcd.print(RPM1[0]);
           }
           else if (settings==2)
           {
              lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
              lcd.print(timer2);
              lcd.setCursor(12, 0); 
              lcd.print("; T3"); 
              lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
              lcd.print(RPM2[3]);
              lcd.print(RPM2[2]);
              lcd.print(RPM2[1]);
              lcd.print(RPM2[0]);
           }
           else if (settings==0)
           {
              lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
              lcd.print(timer);
              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
              lcd.print("; T1");

              lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
              lcd.print(RPM[3]); 
              lcd.print(RPM[2]); 
              lcd.print(RPM[1]); 
              lcd.print(RPM[0]); 
           }




        }
    }
    else if(RPM_Timer=='A' && key_start_stop=='#' && customKey!='C')
    {

        if (settings==0)
        {


            lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
            lcd.print("; T1");
            toggle_RPM=0;


                if (toggle==0 )
                {
                  timer[1]=customKey;
                  toggle=1;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer);
                }
                else
                {
                  timer[0]=customKey;
                  toggle=0;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer);
                }

          }    

        else if (settings==1)
        {


            lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
            lcd.print("; T2");
            toggle_RPM=0;


                if (toggle==0 )
                {
                  timer1[1]=customKey;
                  toggle=1;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer1);
                }
                else
                {
                  timer1[0]=customKey;
                  toggle=0;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer1);
                }

          }    

        else 
        {

            settings=2;
            lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
            lcd.print("; T3");
            toggle_RPM=0;


                if (toggle==0 )
                {
                  timer2[1]=customKey;
                  toggle=1;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer2);
                }
                else
                {
                  timer2[0]=customKey;
                  toggle=0;

                  lcd.setCursor(10, 0);
                  lcd.print(timer2);
                }

          }    

    }


    else if(RPM_Timer=='B' && key_start_stop=='#')
    {
        //  Serial.println(RPM);

          if (settings==0)
          {

              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
              lcd.print("; R1");
              if (toggle_RPM>=4)
                  toggle_RPM=0;


              if (toggle_RPM==0 )
              {
                RPM[3]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM[3]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==1 )
              {
                RPM[2]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM[2]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==2 )
              {
                RPM[1]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM[1]);
              }

              else
              {
                RPM[0]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM[0]);
              }

              toggle_RPM++; 
          }

          else if (settings==1)
          {

              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
              lcd.print("; R2");
              if (toggle_RPM>=4)
                  toggle_RPM=0;


              if (toggle_RPM==0 )
              {
                RPM1[3]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM1[3]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==1 )
              {
                RPM1[2]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM1[2]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==2 )
              {
                RPM1[1]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM1[1]);
              }

              else
              {
                RPM1[0]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM1[0]);
              }

              toggle_RPM++; 
          }

          else
          {
              settings=2;

              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
              lcd.print("; R3");
              if (toggle_RPM>=4)
                  toggle_RPM=0;


              if (toggle_RPM==0 )
              {
                RPM2[3]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(12, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM2[3]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==1 )
              {
                RPM2[2]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(13, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM2[2]);
              }
              else if (toggle_RPM==2 )
              {
                RPM2[1]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM2[1]);
              }

              else
              {
                RPM2[0]=customKey;

                lcd.setCursor(15, 1);
                lcd.print(RPM2[0]);
              }

              toggle_RPM++; 
          }
    }
  }

   lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
   lcd.print("FAN RPM IS :");
  if(key_start_stop=='*' && T>0)
  {
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print("FAN IS ON...T:");
      if (T>9)
      {
          lcd.print(T);  
      }
      else
      {
          lcd.print("0");
          lcd.print(T);
      }


      lcd.setCursor(12, 2);
      if(key_value1!='1')
      {
          switch (key_value)
          {
            case '2':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 51);
              lcd.print("0200");
              break;
            case '3':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 77);
              lcd.print("0300");
              break;
            case '4':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 102);
              lcd.print("0400");
              break;
            case '5':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 128);
              lcd.print("0500");
              break;
            case '6':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 153);
              lcd.print("0600");
              break;
            case '7':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 179);
              lcd.print("0700");
              break;
            case '8':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 204);
              lcd.print("0800");
              break;
            case '9':
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 230);
              lcd.print("0900");
              break;
            default:
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 35);
              lcd.print("0100");
              break;
          }
      }
      else
      {
              analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 255);
              lcd.print("1000");
      }

 }
 else
 {        
          lcd.setCursor(0, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col1 
          lcd.print("FAN OFF.T:");
          if (toggle1==1)
          {
             lcd.setCursor(10, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col15 
             lcd.print(timer);
             toggle1=0;
            // settings=0;
            if(RPM_Timer=='A')
            {
              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col15 
              lcd.print("; T0"); 
            }
            else
            {
              lcd.setCursor(12, 0);// lcd cursor set to row1 & col15 
              lcd.print("; R0"); 
            }

          }

          analogWrite(RPM_Pin, 0);
          digitalWrite(RPM_Pin, LOW);

 }

if (v_time>=80)
{
  v_time=0;
  timer_virtual();
}
else
{
  v_time++;
}




}

//================================================================================//
//      
//================================================================================//
void timer_virtual()
{
  if (key_start_stop=='*' && T>0)
  {
    T--;
  }
  else if (key_start_stop=='*')
  {

    //key_start_stop='#';


    settings--;
  //  Serial.println(settings);


    if (settings==1 || settings_bit==true)
    {
      // timer="00";
       key_start_stop=='*';
       T=timer1.toInt();

       key_value=RPM1[2]; 
       key_value1=RPM1[3]; 


       settings_bit=false;
    }
    else if (settings==0)
    {
    //   timer1="00";
       key_start_stop=='*';
       T=timer2.toInt();

       key_value=RPM2[2]; 
       key_value1=RPM2[3];

      // Serial.println(settings);

    }
    else
    {
      key_start_stop='#';
      settings=0;
      toggle1=1;

    }


  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using Arduino, BLDC won't run with analogWrite function You have to use `servo.write(val)` 
function for BLSC.

```
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo

pos = 50;

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on D9 to the servo object 
} 

void loop() 
{ 
    // The min and max value is 0 and 180
    //Change pos variable according to your requirement
    myservo.write(pos);    
    delay(40); 
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way of controlling a BLDC motor apart from using the servo library? I have done my project using servo library, however, the rpm is not consistent. My supervisor insists that I use a different way and not using the servo library so that I can control the motor by setting the rpm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some little more control then you can use the servo.writeMicroseconds() function. It sends a pulse of the specified length in microseconds to the bldc motor.

For example: servo.writeMicroseconds(1000) sends a pulse of 1000 microseconds.

More info about this function: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/servo/writemicroseconds/

I know, you asked for a solution without the servo library. But i think this will help you because it is more low-level than servo.write() and gives you more control over the bldc motor and results in better results. You can always look inside the servo library to extract the writeMicroseconds function and modify it to fit your needs.